# how to fetch data from sqlite table and display it in textview in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have been working on some sqlite database and i have created one table,and have successfully inserted data,How to fetch the data and display in a textview?

```
 public class EmployeeTable{     
 public static final String KEY_NAME = "emp_name";        
 public static final String KEY_DESIGNATION = "emp_designation";        
 public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";      

 private static final String TAG = "EmployeeTable";    
 private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;    
 private SQLiteDatabase mDb;  

 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "employee_database";    
 private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "employee";    
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

 /**
  * Database creation sql statement
  */  
 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
   "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key    autoincrement, "
   + KEY_NAME +" text not null, " + KEY_DESIGNATION + " text not null);";

 private final Context mCtx;

 private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

   DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
     super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
     Log.i(TAG, "Creating DataBase: " + DATABASE_CREATE);
     db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
   }`
```

**following in my main class:**

```
    public class SqliteDBActivity extends Activity {  
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */  
      private static final String TAG = "EmployeeTable";  
       @Override  
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
           setContentView(R.layout.main);  
           EmployeeTable employeeTable = new EmployeeTable(this);  
        employeeTable.open();  
        employeeTable.createEmployee("Prashant Thakkar", "Tech Lead");  
        employeeTable.createEmployee("Pranay anand", "Tech Lead");  
        employeeTable.createEmployee("rajeev kumar", "Tech Lead");  
        Log.i(TAG, "Fetching record...");  
      employeeTable.close();   
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
   this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

       Cursor cursor = this.db.query(constantValues.TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "emailid" },null, null, null, null, null);
  if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
     do {
        String emailid=cursor.getString(0); // Here you can get data from table and stored in string if it has only one string.
       textview.setText(emailid);


     } while (cursor.moveToNext());
  }
  if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
     cursor.close();
  }
  if(db!=null)
  {
      db.close();
  }
```

}

if it has mutiple data and stored in more than one textview. you have to store it list  and then take the data from list and set to the textview as follows,

```
     List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
     Cursor cursor = this.db.query(constantValues.TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "emailid"},null, null, null, null, null); // here emailid is the field name in the table and contantValues.TABLE_NAME is the table name 
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
     do {
        list.add(cursor.getString(0)); 

     } while (cursor.moveToNext());
  }
```

then take the data from list and set to the textview. for further reference check the [this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) link

Answer (score 1):

```
private SQLiteDatabase database; DatabaseHelperClass dbHelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(this, nameofyourdatabase);

    database = dbHelper.openDataBase(); String qry = "select * from table WHERE yourcolumn"; String stringfortextview;


    Cursor c = database.rawQuery(qry, null);

    c.moveToFirst();
    if (!c.isAfterLast())
    {
        do
        {
            stringfortextview = c.getString(4);
        }
        while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close(); TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView); tv.setText(stringfortextview);
```